# Python - Printing to Shell with getMouse() - graphics.py

Tags: python, shell, printing, python-3.x

I have the very simple program as followed: Python 3.3.2

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    print("Click your mouse to exit")

    win = GraphWin()

# Draw graphics here

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

main()
```

This is obviously a very simple program. All I am trying to do is create a function that opens up the graphics window, draws the graphics, and then tells the user in the shell to "click the mouse to exit". However, the problem is that I can't get the print statement to show up in the shell until after I click the mouse and the graphics window closes. So, is there a way to be able to print a statement while using *getMouse()*?

Comment: FYI, I can't repeat your problem. I ran your exact program (after downloading the newest graphics.py from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/), and the message appeared in my shell window before I clicked the mouse. I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Python 3.2.3. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ could it be that i am running it in Wing IDE?

Comment: It's certainly possible. Can you try running this program directly from the command line?